# How does one filter pcap (e.g. tcpdump) files by content regex match?

Tags: c++, python, pcap, packet-capture, tcpdump

I have some large pcap (packet capture) files collected with tcpdump.  I would like to filter out packets that contain a specific string.  I want my output to still be in pcap format.  I've found several ways of only displaying packets matching a regex from a pcap file, but what I need is to filter such files rather than filter out the display (e.g. stdout) of the packets.  The output needs to be pcap files with the matched packets removed.

I suspect dpkt (a python module) might help, but I'd prefer to do this using an existing (C/C++) tool, if possible.  I'll accept code as an answer (maybe a good dpkt example with benchmarks will convince me to just go that way as well ;-)).

Thanks in advance!

**Answer:**

Per Nim's answer, it's possible to do this via Wireshark/tshark.  For others' reference, here's an example commandline, where I check for the string match within udp packets (this example can be built on to do tcp or specific protocol field searching):

```
tshark -r infile  -R 'not udp matches "my_search_string"' -w outfile
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Surely if you can filter out the display you could just redirect stdout to a file?

Comment: Right, but my requirement is that the output is pcap, not string representations of the packets as you'd get printed on stdout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [website](http://www.joshuarobinson.net/docs/libpcap_offline.html) has a very nice example of how you can read the pcap file in C, a quick google search will reveal how you can re-write the file.

Alternatively, AFAIK Wireshark may allow you to do this already - i.e. open the file, apply a filter and save the file (and a quick run through Wireshark - reveals that it does indeed offer this).

Comment: Yes! tshark does this.  Thanks for the pointer.  I am updating the question to better format the commandline.